# Gulp-inject inject file wrong path

Tags: gulp, gulp-inject

I have tried to inject file to `index.html` file but the path file is not correct. Could you tell me why it happen ?

Folder structure

[image]

gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('index', function () {

    let target = gulp.src('./src/index.html');
    // let sources = gulp.src(['./src/resources/js/*.js'],  {read: false})
    //     .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    //     .pipe(gulp.dest('./src'))
    var vendorStream = gulp.src(['./src/resources/js/*.js'])
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
    return target.pipe(inject(vendorStream)).pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
})
```

The index file was generated by gulp

[image]

Comment: Does inject(vendorStream, { relative:true }) fix it?

Comment: @Mark
Yes it fixed, I found other way by using ignorePath option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
return target.pipe(inject(vendorStream)).pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
```

to:

```
return target.pipe(inject(vendorStream, { relative:true })).pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
```

See [injecting files relative to the target file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject#injecting-files-relative-to-target-files):

> By default the injected file paths are relative to each source file's
>   cwd (see options.ignorePath). If options.relative is set to true each
>   injected path will be relative to each target file's directory
>   instead.

So the

```
relative: true
```

option will make the js file(s) injected be relative to the target html file, which in your case are in the same directory.